# "(many fewer/a lot of fewer/little fewer/much fewer) people than usual"

Tags: comparative-constructions

> There are (many fewer/a lot of fewer/little fewer/much fewer) people than usual in the street.

How do I know the difference between them?

Comment: I'd opt for *"....considerably fewer people..."* to avoid two contradictory words' combination!

Comment: Well, many fewer, little fewer and much are just wrong, but I can't tell you why.  The other one is ok.

Comment: @MaulikV They're not contradictory. You could see my answer if you wanted to know why. :)

Comment: @Andy They are definitely not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### Prenote:

*A lot of fewer* is incorrect. *Of* comes before a noun, and doesn't exist in the adverbial form (which you want to use here, with an adjective), so it's *a lot fewer*.
*Little* and *a little* [are different](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/little-a-little-few-a-few). I assume that you wanted to ask about ***a** little*.

### Short answer

> **many fewer / a lot fewer / much fewer**, and **a little fewer**

None of these adv+adj  collocations are wrong. The first three of them mean almost the same thing: that the difference in number is big. The last one means the opposite: the difference in number is small.
But in terms of prevalence, there are better choices to make:

When there's big difference in number, the most common expression by far is **far fewer**:

> *There are **far fewer** people than usual in the street.*

And when the difference is small, the most common expression appears to be **slightly fewer**:

> *There are **slightly fewer** people than usual in the street.*

### Long Answer

To cite an authority, this is what Longman Dictionary has to say about *fewer*:

> **fewer** [quantifier]: a smaller number of people or things. **Fewer** is used with countable nouns:
>   *Spending cuts will mean fewer social workers.*
>
> **far fewer/a lot fewer**:
>   *There were far fewer women at the conference this year than last.*

(Not a complete definition (*fewer* is not just a quantifier and has more common word partners than *far* and *a lot*), but was still worth mentioning.)

Now I'm going to search [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for `[be] . . . fewer than` <sup>**†**</sup>, and present you with some statistics regarding what kinds of adverbs are how frequently used in that gap. This is to get a smaller sample to go through and get first clues; more relaxed searches will be done later on.

> - [be] far fewer than: 22
> - [be] considerably fewer than: 5
> - [be] a lot fewer than: 2
> - [be] substantially fewer than: 2
> - [be] a few fewer than: 1
> - [be] many fewer than: 1

I left less relevant results out of the list, like *[be] probably fewer than*: 7, *[be] two fewer than*: 2, *[be] X percent fewer than*: 2, etc.

As you see, **far** is by far the most prevalent one, and **considerably** comes second (, and both of them were offered in the comments/answer before). But are the other options *wrong*?

One thing that throws doubt on expressions like *many fewer* or *a lot fewer* is that they seem self-contradictory: How can there be a few of both Xs and Ys, and yet Xs be ***many** fewer/more* than Ys?! How can they both be a few *and* the difference between them be many?

The answer is simple: **comparative and superlative adjectives don't go by that logic**. You can say "*The Earth is smaller than the Sun*" without implying that any of them is small, and you can say of two newborn twins that "*This one is older than that one*" without suggesting that any of them is old.
Therefor, it's technically correct (but practically not best) to say "*There are fewer people than ants*", even though they're both many. (A more usual phrasing: "*There are more ants than people*".)

Another problem that some people seem to have with *much/a little fewer* is that *much* and *a little* are used before uncountable nouns, and *few* is used for/with countable nouns: you can't have **few water(s)* or **much apples*.

The answer to this one is that it's true for *much* and *a little* when they are determiners, and not necessarily when they are adverbs. You can safely say "*There are much more thieves here than there are policemen*" and "*My pimples are a little more than yours*".

Let's explore more of COCA:

> - far fewer: 824
> - many fewer: 127
> - a lot fewer: 96
> - considerably fewer: 40
> - much fewer: 29
> - substantially fewer: 27
> - a few fewer: 5
> - a little fewer: 2

***Far fewer*** is still on top, but the order of the other expressions has changed dramatically. Most noticeably, ***many fewer*** has surpassed all the others by a good margin.

***Many fewer*** [comes second in Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+fewer%2C+many+fewer%2C+a+lot+fewer%2C+considerably+fewer%2C+much+fewer%2C+substantially+fewer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfar%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20lot%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsiderably%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubstantially%20fewer%3B%2Cc0) too:
[image]

And here's [the Ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slightly+fewer%2C+a+little+fewer%2Ca+bit+fewer%2Csomewhat+fewer%2Crather+fewer%2Cmoderately+fewer%2Cto+a+certain+extent+fewer%2Cfaintly+fewer%2Cvaguely+fewer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslightly%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bit%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomewhat%20fewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crather%20fewer%3B%2Cc0) for when the difference is not big:
[image]

Note that even for *a little fewer*, which finished second to last in the previous Ngram, there are [many legitimate instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20little%20fewer%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) in Google books.

---

<sub>**†**  `...`: I used it to represent a gap of up to two words;

`[be]`: In COCA it means *any of the various forms of the verb `be`*;

`[be]` and `than` added to reduce the number of the results and make it easier to go through them.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`Much` does not fit with `Fewer`; *much* refers to amounts rather than numbers of things. "much less" is fine to things measured that way (e.g. "much less water in the jar..."), and `fewer` is the right word for numbers of things (i.e. *people* in this case), but `much` does not fit with it.

`a lot of fewer` is also wrong, in two ways. First, the `of` should be left out: `a lot fewer`. Secondly, `a lot` has the same problem, to some degree, as `much`, above: you can have `a lot less`, but not (usually) `a lot fewer`.

`many fewer` is the best of the three options given.

However, as @Maulik-v commented `considerably fewer` is even better, since you avoid having the reader needing think about a word that commonly indicates a greater number being reversed to mean the magnitude of "fewer". Another, perhaps less formal choice might be `far fewer`.

Comment: -1. "Much" _does_ fit with "fewer".  You could see my answer if you wanted to know why. :)